# Hiding m2m-field @ admin, during certain conditions

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, many-to-many

I have:
a Django-admin model containing a small number of fields, of which two are of importance.
One is an IntegerField, connected to a list of pre-defined choices, ranging from 1 to 5.
The other is am2m-field, connected to a model which has some 30k+ objects.

What i'd like is to ONLY display the (realllly heavy) m2m-field when editing an object, which holds all but one of the available choices (1-4).

I.e: When creating new objects it should'nt show, as well as when editing objects that holds an integer value of 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by writing a custom change_form with accompanying admin-method.